# How to use a fixture in a pytest skipif marker?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a `py.test` function like the follows:

```
def my_test(self, driver):
    # Do something with the driver
```

which uses a `driver` fixture (defined in `conftest.py`).

Now, I need to check something before running this test. If that check fails, I need to skip this test. Here is what I tried:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(not driver.check(),
                    reason="Some check negative.")
def my_test(self, driver):
    # Do something with the driver
```

But that marker uses a fixture itself (it might be the same fixture, or a *different* fixture, it does not matter here). Is there a **simple** way I can use a fixture in a `skipif` marker?

Comment: Fixtures are injected into test functions, they don't work at import time as in decorators. You might be able to use the fixure function directly by calling it.

Comment: What do you mean 'by calling it'? I am calling a fixture, no?

Comment: Try `driver()`.

Comment: Even if you manage to call the fixture function directly, this behaviour is deprecated. Instead of using fixture in `skip` decorator, call `pytest.skip` in fixture function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not skip the test from inside the driver fixture? Then every fixture can decide for itself whether it needs to skip all tests that depend on it.

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def driver():
    if not check_driver():
        pytest.skip("Driver could not be loaded")
    return get_driver()
```

See also [Skip test from inside a fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330369/skip-test-from-inside-a-fixture)